# How to plot Poincaré map for system consists of 3 degree of freedom

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

**here the equations of motion and data I need to plot Poincaré map for this system**:

```
data = { Subscript[f, 1] -> 0.001, Subscript[f, 2] -> 0.002,Subscript[c, 1] -> 0.002,
Subscript[c, 2]-> 0.005,Subscript[\[Omega], 1] -> 0.1, W -> 0.14, Subscript[p, 1] -> 0.65,Subscript[p, 2] -> 0.28, r -> 0.004, p -> 1.167, \[Alpha] -> 0.2 ,Subscript[\[Xi], s] -> .14,Subscript[\[Mu], 1] -> .05, \[Gamma] -> 0.01,Subscript[c, p] -> 9.3, Subscript[R, p] -> 100}

equations = {-r p^2 Cos[p \[Tau]] - Cos[\[Tau] Subscript[p, 1]] Subscript[f, 1] + z[\[Tau]] + 
3 \[Alpha] Subscript[\[Xi], s]^2 z[\[Tau]] + 3 \[Alpha] Subscript[\[Xi], s] z[\[Tau]]^2 + \[Alpha] z[\[Tau]]^3 +Subscript[\[Mu], 1] \[Upsilon][\[Tau]] -r p^2 Sin[p \[Tau]] \[Phi][\[Tau]] + 1/2 W^2 \[Phi][\[Tau]]^2 + Subscript[c, 1] Derivative[1][z][\[Tau]] -Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]]^2 -z[\[Tau]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]]^2 + (z^\[Prime]\[Prime])[\[Tau]] ==0, -p^2 r Sin[p \[Tau]] -Cos[\[Tau] Subscript[p, 2]] Subscript[f, 2]-p^2 r Sin[p \[Tau]] z[\[Tau]] + W^2 \[Phi][\[Tau]] +p^2 r Cos[p \[Tau]] \[Phi][\[Tau]] +W^2 z[\[Tau]] \[Phi][\[Tau]] +p^2 r Cos[p \[Tau]] z[\[Tau]] \[Phi][\[Tau]] -1/6 W^2 \[Phi][\[Tau]]^3 - 1/6 W^2 z[\[Tau]] \[Phi][\[Tau]]^3 +Subscript[c, 2] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]] +2 Derivative[1][z][\[Tau]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]] +2 z[\[Tau]] Derivative[1][z][\[Tau]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][\[Tau]] + (\[Phi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[\[Tau]] +2 z[\[Tau]] (\[Phi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[\[Tau]] +z[\[Tau]]^2 (\[Phi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[\[Tau]] ==0, \[Upsilon][\[Tau]]/(Subscript[c, p] Subscript[R, p] Subscript[\[Omega],1]) - (\[Gamma] Derivative[1][z][\[Tau]])/Subscript[c, p] +Derivative[1][\[Upsilon]][\[Tau]] == 0};
```

Comment: Could you include how these are solved in `NDSolve`?

Comment: These can't be solved in `NDSolve` because it can't make sense of taking the unknown functions to the power of prime prime. The correct syntax is simply `z''[tau]`. [Here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/PoincareSections.html) is an example of computing a Poincaré map with `WhenEvent`.